# Kafka connect producer poll mechansim

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, splunk

I poll data from splunk logs and write to a topic. Every time poll runs, how does it know it should get new set of records. Do I need to store last read timestamp from logs and store it in sourceoffset and when poll is run next time, do I need to have logic to get data after that timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

> do I need to have logic to get data after that timestamp

Yes, otherwise I imagine you're constantly polling the same time slice of logs

> how does it know it should get new set of records.

"new" is relative. Poll loop will constantly run. It's up to you to tell the command which set of records to send to the topic